# Empty Auto-Renewing iOS In-App purchases from SKProductsRequest initWithProductIdentifiers

Tags: ios, react-native, in-app-purchase

I've made an iOS in-app Auto-Renewable Subscription, now I'm trying to allow users to purchase it in a React-Native app.

I've found [`react-native-in-app-utils`](https://github.com/chirag04/react-native-in-app-utils), but can't seem to even load my products. I have 3 "products" (auto-renewable subscriptions) in iTunes connect, but trying to load them with:

```
var products = [
  'com.xxxx.app.monthly',
  'com.xxxx.app.6months',
  'com.xxxx.app.year',
];

InAppUtils.loadProducts(products, (error, products) => {
  console.log('products:', products);
});
```

just logs "products: []".

Digging a little deeper, I've added some additional logging to the objective-c code doing the querying, and it looks like:

```
NSLog(@"loading products %@", productIdentifiers);
if([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments]){
    SKProductsRequest *productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc]
                                          initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithArray:productIdentifiers]];
    productsRequest.delegate = self;
    _callbacks[RCTKeyForInstance(productsRequest)] = callback;
    [productsRequest start];
} else {
    callback(@[@"not_available"]);
}
```

Then in the callback:

```
NSLog(@"products response %@", response.products);
products = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:response.products];
NSMutableArray *productsArrayForJS = [NSMutableArray array];     
for(SKProduct *item in response.products) {
    NSDictionary *product = @{
    ...
```

This will log "loading products" with my product ids, as expected. But then "products response ()"... empty response.

Those products are listed in iTunes connect as "Ready to Submit". And they've been added to the app info under In-App Purchases. What gives? Why aren't the products showing up?

Comment: have you submit the contract for paid product from iTunes?

Comment: Yes. That should already be done.

Comment: Did you check Cleared for Sale box in the iTunes connect for each subscription?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was an administrative issue, not a technical one. Project Manager hadn't put through the paid app agreement.